# VB.Net: DataGridView seems as if it is piercing the form

Tags: vb.net, forms, datagridview, render, graphic

I'm having a graphical issue with a **DataGridView**.

[image: Issue screenshot]

As you can see the form looks like **pierced** from the **DataGridView** control.

The code of the **DataGridView** instantiation is this:

```
Private Sub pageAlarms_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.Width = MainForm.Width
    Me.Height = MainForm.Height
    Me.Dock = DockStyle.Fill


    dgvActiveAlarms = New DataGridView() 
    almBasePanel.Controls.Add(dgvActiveAlarms)

    With dgvActiveAlarms
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        .Name = "activeAlarmsTable"
        .AutoSizeRowsMode =
            DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
        .ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Single
        .CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.Single
        .GridColor = Color.Black
        .RowHeadersVisible = False

        .ColumnCount = 5

    End With
End Sub
```

I tried also to **create the control from the designer**, but with same result.

The page which contains the **almBasePanel** is a **user control**, instantiated in the main form load.

*I could not find a topic with similar issue so I decided to submit this question, forgive me if I posted for a redundant argument.*

Thank you,
Giuse

Comment: Have you set the `TransparencyKey` property of the form?

Comment: Yes! It was set to **Transparent**, now looks good! Thank you very much